# Retrieve values from a nedted list with an inconsistent number of nesting to one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

The answers at

[How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

do not answer my question, I am talking about an **inconsistent number of neste lists** .

Suppose this is the list:

```
list_a = [
    [[1, 2]],
    [1, 1, 2],
    [[1, 2, 2], [3], [3,4]],
    [[[1,1], [1,2,3], [1,2,1]], [1,1]]
]
```

I would like to get all values in one list, like this:

```
list_b = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: You need to recursively flatten each level of the list. See for example @pylang answer on the duplicate.

Comment: @Nick I am talking about an inconsistent number of neste lists , The answers there do not help

Comment: The answer I pointed to will absolutely flatten your structure: https://ideone.com/eBqQGx

Comment: This will solve:   `def retrieve_valous(lst):
    new_list = []
    for i in lst:
        if type(i) != list:
            new_list.append(i)
        else:
            new_list.extend(retrieve_valous(i))
    return new_list`

Comment: There are also other answers from EL_DON, pylang, mmj, Alon Gouldman, ...